# Store email body in table using Laravel 5.3 Mailable

Tags: email, laravel-5.3

I want to store the email body in my communications table. My controller:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeEmail($subscription));

Communication::create([
    'to'       =>  $user->email,
    'subject'       => 'Welcome Email',
    'body'       => '???'
]);
```

My email goes out (successfully) and I am able to create a Communication record, but have no idea how to retrieve the email body.

After reading the [Mail manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail), I thought I could work with an event:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSentMessage',
    ],
];
```

But here I get only the full plain text email. If I create an instance of the mail, with:

```
$email = Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeEmail($subscription));
```

the outcome of `dd($email);` is `null`.

Some extra info, in my WelcomeEmail.php, I am using a view:

```
public function build()
{   
    return $this->view('emails.welcome_email');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, hopefully it can help other people.

```
$body = View::make('emails.welcome_email')
        ->with('subscription', $this->subscription)
        ->with('template', $this->template)
        ->render();
```

I rendered the view and saved it in the body variable.

Comment: Laravel to suggest to render email https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#rendering-mailables But in this way you can't save the HTTP header in example or set a status of email to SENT in example... i have same problem

Answer (score 2):

You can directly do this to render Mailable and store it in a variable

```
$html = (new WelcomeEmail($subscription))->render();
```